# How to bind two source of data into a datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

my problem is the following : 
I have a datagrid of "salesTable" using entity framework, I load the datagrid with this code :

```
salesDataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.salesTables.ToList();
```

one of the columns of salesTable is customerId which is a foreign key of customerTable, now I want to show the customerName instead of the customerId in the datagrid but I don't know how.

salesTable is as the following :

```
public int saleId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> customerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> saleDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> invoiceId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> total{ get; set; }

    public virtual customerTable customerTable { get; set; }
    public virtual fac fac { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Sale_Detail> Sale_Detail { get; set; }
```

Please help!

Comment: Can we see how `salesTables` is defined and populated?

Comment: please check again the post, I put it there 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this ViewModel:

```
  public class GridViewModel
    {
        public int SaleId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        //other properties you want
    }
```

Then use GridViewModel in query:

```
var result = _db.salesTables.Include(x => x.customerTable)
                            .Select(x => new GridViewModel()
                          {
                               SaleId = x.saleId,
                               CustomerName = x.customerTable.CustomerName
                           }).ToList();
```

and finally:

```
salesDataGrid.ItemsSource = result;
```